# Strange cursor behavior with text property invisible

Tags: text-properties, cursor

I am trying to hide some text in my buffer using text property invisible. This works fine, except that the cursor is not moving correctly when the text is hidden. To reproduce this clearly I think I need a large text file, so to generate a dummy text file `t.txt` :

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1; i<1400; i++) { printf "%4d ", i ; print "abcdedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; }}' > t.txt
```

Then consider the lisp code:

```
(defvar *my-hide* nil)
(defun my-hide ()
  (interactive)
  (setq *my-hide* (not *my-hide*))
  (put-text-property 1 32968 'invisible *my-hide*))
```

When I open open the file `t.txt` and position the cursor at the beginning of the buffer and run `(my-hide)` it correctly hides the first 1000 lines. But if I now try to move the cursor with, for example, the page down key, it is moving one character position to the right on the first line but the right scroll bar is still moving. If I hit it again, it jumps to line 1026, the next time it jumps to line 1013 (the right scroll bar is moving down each time)..

I am using Emacs version 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to that I used `(global-set-key [next] 'pager-page-down)` and `(require 'pager)` in my `~/.emacs` init file. It seems to work correctly if I remove those lines..